# jQuery hide an element with slideup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a div which works perfectly but instead of it just vanishing instantly I would like to use the jQuery `slide` to hide it with a little animation.

```
$(".hide-reply").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.media').find('.reply-body').hide();
});
```

I tried change the line to (as per the jQuery docs) -

```
$(this).closest('.media').find('.reply-body').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 100);
```

But this throws an `Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function`
I'm not sure I understand this error.

Comment: why not use `.slideUp()`

Comment: see this demo https://jsfiddle.net/trbw1d04/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.animate()` , setting `height` to `0`

```js
$("div").animate({
  height:0
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.slideUp(100)` in your project;

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').mouseover(function(){



$(this).slideUp();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hover <br> over <br> me <br></div>
```

Use [.slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)